# XML-RPC wp.upload working fine But make Image corrupted

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried many ways to upload image to wordpress using xml-rpc and getting perfect responce with an array of file name, path and file type. Still if i look at image in wordpress it make a 0 byte corrupted image file.

I have made a class to operate all queries like create post/ edit post/ delete post etc. All working file just wp.uploadfile mot working well.

Here is my function for image upload.

```
function upload_pic($url, $pic, $type='image/jpg')
{
    $fs = filesize($url);
    $file = fopen($url, 'rb');
    $filedata = fread($file, $fs);
    fclose($file);

    $content = array(
        'name'  => $pic,
        'type'  => $type,
        'bits'  => new IXR_Base64($filedata), 
        'overwrite' => false 
    );

    $params = array(1,$this->UserName,$this->PassWord,$content,true);
    return $this->send_request('wp.uploadFile',$params);
}
```

I am getting following responce

```
   Array
   (
       [id] => 190
       [file] => P_1364799102.jpg
       [url] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/P_13647991025.jpg
       [type] => image/jpg
   )
```

Response looks good but still image file is corrupted with 0 byte.

Please help me with this. I have also tried 'metaWeblog.newMediaObject' but problem still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  Have found a fix it is working fine now.

```
function upload_pic($postid, $myFile, $name, $type='image/jpeg')
{
    $rpcurl = $this->XMLRPCURL;;
    $username = $this->UserName;
    $password = $this->PassWord;

    $file=file_get_contents($myFile);
    $filetype = $type;
    $filename = $name;

    xmlrpc_set_type($file,'base64'); // <-- required!
    $params = array($postid,$username,$password,array('name'=>$filename,'type'=>$filetype,'bits'=>$file,'overwrite'=>false));

    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.uploadFile',$params);
    $result = xmlrpc_decode($this->go($request,$rpcurl));
    return $result;
}
```

Thanks